# Creating User Login Session with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

First of, allow me to point out that am new to android development and at this very moment am trying to store a user login session using SharedPreferences and having done a bit to create myself a class SessionManager to handle that, i got no error anyways but, each time i logged in, am quickly redirected to the LoginActivty again.

**SessionManager.java**

```java
package com.example.drawerlayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class SessionManager {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "LOGIN";
    private static final String LOGIN = "IS_LOGIN";
    public static final String NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String TYPE = "TYPE";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }


    public void createSession(String name, String email, String type){
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, true);
        editor.putString(NAME, name);
        editor.putString(EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(TYPE, type);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void checkLoggin(){
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((MainActivity) context).finish();
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put(NAME, sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, null));
        user.put(EMAIL, sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL, null));
        user.put(TYPE, sharedPreferences.getString(TYPE, null));

        return user;
    }



    public void logOut(){
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((MainActivity) context).finish();
    }
}
```

and **SessionManager.java** is used in LoginActivity like so:

```java
String name = details.getString("username").trim();
String email = details.getString("email").trim();
String type = details.getString("type").trim();

//CREATE SESSION
sessionManager.createSession(name,email,type);
```

and in **MainActivity.java** like

```java
sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
sessionManager.checkLoggin();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's actual problem that you are facing and what's the expected result please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your String variable names once again!

- `String PREF_NAME` is for **getting the preference.**
- `String LOGIN` is for **addressing the value to check if the user is logged in or not**

## Your Mistake:

- ***Function*** **createSession(String name, String email, String type)**

  1. You are updating the value of `String PREF_NAME` instead of `String LOGIN`

## Solution:

- ***Function*** **createSession(String name, String email, String type)**

  1. Updating the value of `String LOGIN` instead of `String PREF_NAME`in **line no 29** of **SessionManager.java**

Answer (score 1):

You are updating wrong key in `createSession` method.

Replace `PREF_NAME` with `LOGIN` in `createSession`. And your code will work as expected.

```
public void createSession(String name, String email, String type){

    // Check below line...
    editor.putBoolean(LOGIN, true);

    editor.putString(NAME, name);
    editor.putString(EMAIL, email);
    editor.putString(TYPE, type);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have forgotten to put a boolean field LOGIN in your session manager's create session.. modify  createSession Method as below

```
public void createSession(String name, String email, String type,Boolean isLoggedIn){

    editor.putString(NAME, name);
    editor.putString(EMAIL, email);
    editor.putString(TYPE, type);
    editor.putBoolean(LOGIN,isLoggedIn)
    editor.apply();
}
```

And then if login success in login activity then call like this

```
    String name = details.getString("username").trim();
String email = details.getString("email").trim();
String type = details.getString("type").trim();

//CREATE SESSION
sessionManager.createSession(name,email,type,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

alright sharedpreference values are saving in xml file which contain its key and value so each of value will be generate on first attempt of login so why don't you check if any value is exists in sharedpreference or not by this way.. put this code to your sessionHandler

```
 public static boolean preferenceExists(String key){
    return  sharedPreferences.contains(key);
}
```

it will return boolean flag if any value is exists there or not so simply do check if **preferenceExists()** or not.... if not then redirect it do login activity else redirect where you want

**suggestion :** create splashscreen where you can verify these things

Comment: great idea. @Black mamba